# Pandas DataFrame: how to reference to multiple sub set of row from itself?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I want to get a dataframe which included multiple subset from itself. For example: `DataFrame(data = a[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])`. I want build a dataframe with iloc[0,3] and iloc[6:9] which resulting: `DataFrame(data = a[1,2,3,6,7,8])`.

Currently I am doing like this which is keep doing data copying and very slow:

```
if my_df is not None:                
    domain += 1
    new_domain = df.iloc[begin_iloc: begin_of_next_iloc]
    new_domain['domain'] = domain
    my_df = my_df.append(new_domain)
else:
    my_df = df.iloc[begin_iloc: begin_of_next_iloc]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`numpy.r_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) for concanecate indices:

```
print (np.r_[0:3, 6:9])
[0 1 2 6 7 8]

print (df.iloc[np.r_[0:3, 6:9]])
   a
0  1
1  2
2  3
6  7
7  8
8  9
```

Comment: number of slice has to be hard coded? Because slice are calculated.

Comment: I think not, you can use `print (np.r_[begin_iloc:begin_of_next_iloc, begin_iloc1:begin_of_next_iloc1])`. But I ma not sure if I understand your question well.